# No power to bathroom lights and two outlets

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, bathroom

Having an issue where my bathroom lights/fans and 2 outlets will not come on. Here is what i know so far:

- No breakers are tripped
- No GCFI are tripped, i reset all of them
- All the breakers at the panel read 120v with respect to the neutral bar
- No voltage at the outlets/lights but the neutrals have continuity with any other neutral in the home.

Unfortunately i don't know which breaker these lights are on (previous owner had no labels) and don't know of any way to find it without power on the circuit.

Any ideas?

Comment: When was the home built or the last major rewire? I ask because modern code they are on the same circuit that only goes to the bathroom, older installs could be part of other room wiring and may change where to start looking.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. When these circuits stopped working, was there anything going on that might have caused the change?

Comment: The house was built in 1989 and so far the wiring has been in pretty good shape. The bathroom is definitely a remodel so the wiring is likely strange. There are two other (working) circuits in the bathroom, one is the outlets tapped from GCFI in the other bathroom. This circuit seems fine and unrelated, there is also a dedicated 20amp breaker but seems like it's just for the jetted tub. I plugged in a vacuum to one of the now non working outlets and used it to clean a vent, the strange thing is that outlet is the end of a run (only one Romex).

Comment: +1 to incorrect wiring in another room.  In my case, a poorly installed ceiling fan in an adjacent bed room was causing all the problems.  The clue was that electricity also stopped working in the closet.  Strangely enough, the ceiling fan (and light fixture) worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

It was an open hot after all, I purchased a wire toner and used it to follow the wires in the wall until I found a box with a faulty wire nut in it. Replaced the hot bundle firmly together and applied a new wire nut all is well.

Thanks all.